# Error in a trigger for counting attachments

Tags: trigger, attachment

I have create the following trigger on Task in order to set as True a field (Questionnaire_attached) if there is an attachment. But It does not work. This message is showed: "Record is read-only" but this field is not read-only. 
Could somebody help me with this?

```
trigger DocumentAttached on Task (after insert , after update) 
{ 
    for(Task tsk : Trigger.new){ 
        Attachment[] attList = [select id, name, body from Attachment where ParentId = :Trigger.new[0].id]; 
        if(attList.size() > 0) { 
            tsk.Questionnaire_attached__c=true; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code need improvement, it break good code standards. Pleas consider this

Answer (score 5):

If you want to update objects in trigger.new, then you need to use a before trigger as opposed to an after trigger.

From the documentation

> **You can use an object to change its own field values using
>   trigger.new, but only in before triggers. In all after triggers,
>   trigger.new is not saved, so a runtime exception is thrown.**

See here.....

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables_considerations.htm

Changing to a before trigger should solve your issue here, but there are still other issues with the trigger.  It will not work in bulk.  You have SOQL in a for loop, which is not recommended.  I would take a look here for some best practices to optimize this trigger as well.

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices

Comment: There is no point to check value on insert. before update should be enough:)

Comment: I guess I don't follow that comment at all.  I didn't suggest anything around checking a value on insert.  Either way, how would you know if there was an attachment on the task without somehow checking it?

Comment: NAh, that is about code - I figured that better add it here than under code. In that way everyone who see your comment can see my additional suggestion to preveriouus code. Sorry that I confused you....

Comment: Makes sense to me Birthus - no TaskNote would ever exist on insert of the Task, so no need to have the trigger execute on before insert.